# Insert a linebreak inside a ionic tag

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework, tags

I'm using ionic to build an app and I want to insert a linebreak inside a ionic tag (that will render a String) so it can display correctly inside its container...

```
<h2>{{caravan.model}}</h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding the class "item-text-wrap" to add line breaks.

```
 <h2 class="item-text-wrap">{{caravan.model}}</h2>
```

Answer (score 4):

One solution using Ionic2 is to use the innerHtml of a div

```
<div class="card-content" [innerHtml]="description"></div>
```

Now you can use any HTML tags like

```
<h1>, <br> or <p></p> etc..
```

in the prop description:string in typescript or javascript class

```
description:string = "<h1>My Header</h1> more text <br> and a break"
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to use `ng-repeat` for that like shown below:
inside **controller.js**

```
$scope.carven = carven;
```

and
use this in **html**

```
<div ng-repeat="data in carven">
   <h2>{{data.model}}</h2>
 </div>
```

Comment: can you provide me fiddle. And if you are using ng-repeat then there is no need of adding line breaks, they are automatically added.

Comment: I solved my problem...The only thing to do was adding "item-text-wrap" inside the class tag in order to add line breaks...Thank you for your answer, anyway.

Comment: great to know @AlisonLopez